# Select Differents routes in app-routing-module with conditional//angular

Tags: angular

I wanted to consult:
I am wanting to select different routes depending on an environment where I am, since I want to separate different projects in the application that share the same path but with different addresses and this is not working. If you could help me I would appreciate it.

app-routing-module:

```
import {PlatformService} from './services/platform.service'
import { ,NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { Router, RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';
import { UsuarioGuard } from './guards/usuario.guard';

let routes: Routes 
@NgModule({
  imports: [
    RouterModule.forRoot(routes)
  ],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})

export class AppRoutingModule {
  constructor( private platformService:PlatformService,
   router: Router) {
    let routes: Routes
    let config = router.config;
    if (this.platformService.inOther()){
      routes = [
           {
             path: 'home',
             loadChildren: () => import('./pages/home/home.module').then( m => m.HomePageModule),
             canActivate: [ UsuarioGuard, PlatformGuard  ]
           },
      ];
    }
    else {
      routes = [
           {
             path: 'home',
             loadChildren: () => import('./pages2/home/home.module').then( m => m.HomePageModule),
             canActivate: [ UsuarioGuard, PlatformGuard  ]
           },
      ];
    }
    config = routes;
    router.resetConfig(config);
   }
}
```

Also try to use gurds but as they are the same path when running the application it recognizes the first Path but the second path is not recognized.

app-routing-module:

Forma2

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '', 
    pathMatch: 'full',
    redirectTo: 'home'
  },
  {
    path: 'home',
    loadChildren: () => import('./pages/home/home.module').then( m => m.HomePageModule),
    canActivate: [ UsuarioGuard ]
  },
{
    path: 'home',
    loadChildren: () => import('./pages2/home/home.module').then( m => m.HomePageModule),
    canActivate: [ UsuarioGuard2 ]
  },
];
@NgModule({
  imports: [
    RouterModule.forRoot(routes, { preloadingStrategy: PreloadAllModules })
  ],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule {}
```

Comment: Can you share stackblitz example?

Comment: How about creating two separate routes and navigate between them with guards?

Comment: I did that test, using the same path but with different guards, what happens is that since there are two identical paths, which for my work have to be, it recognizes the first path but the second does not recognize it.

Comment: Navigate manually with you condition on app.component.ts ngOnInit. create two seperate routes and not use empty path navigation